# Ensure Unique Attribute Values in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to ensure that the attribute's in the `<property_advert>` elements are unique. For example the attribute `agent_advert_reference` should be unique. I want the XML below to fail due to duplicate attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property_adverts xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/XmplifyDerivedSchema.xsd">
    <header>
        <harvest_run_info>
            <harvest_time>12:05:00</harvest_time>
            <harvest_date>2015-10-10</harvest_date>
            <harvester_version>1.0</harvester_version>
            <harvester_path>/Users/xandrani/Sites/property_harvester_new</harvester_path>
        </harvest_run_info>
        <property_agent>
            <company_name>CPS Homes</company_name>
        </property_agent>
    </header>
    <adverts>
        <property_advert agent_advert_reference="X1204" static_advert_url="https://www.example.com/properties/1204" original_html_file="/RandomName/advert_30Sep2015_14436555622486.html">
            <rent_cost>450</rent_cost>
            <rent_frequency>per month</rent_frequency>
            <number_of_bedrooms>4</number_of_bedrooms>
            <available_date>now</available_date>
            <property_description></property_description>
            <main_photo_url>https://www.example.com/properties/X1204/fred.jpg</main_photo_url>
            <branch_name>Brusque Bay</branch_name>
            <property_type>House</property_type>
            <building_name/>
            <street_name>High Street</street_name>
            <postcode>CF11 6BP</postcode>
            <furnished>true</furnished>
            <location_area>Canton</location_area>
        </property_advert>
        <property_advert agent_advert_reference="X1204" static_advert_url="https://www.example.com/properties/1204" original_html_file="/RandomName/advert_30Sep2015_14436555622486.html">
            <rent_cost>450</rent_cost>
            <rent_frequency>per month</rent_frequency>
            <number_of_bedrooms>4</number_of_bedrooms>
            <available_date>now</available_date>
            <property_description></property_description>
            <main_photo_url>https://www.example.com/properties/X1204/fred.jpg</main_photo_url>
            <branch_name>Brusque Bay</branch_name>
            <property_type>House</property_type>
            <building_name/>
            <street_name>High Street</street_name>
            <postcode>CF11 6BP</postcode>
            <furnished>true</furnished>
            <location_area>Canton</location_area>
        </property_advert>
    </adverts>
</property_adverts>
```

My schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
            XML Schema.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="harvest_run_info" type="harvest_run_info_type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="harvest_run_info_type">
        <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="harvest_time" type="xs:time" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="harvest_date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="harvester_version" type="harvester_version_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="harvester_path" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="property_advert" type="property_advert_type"/>    
    <xs:complexType name="property_advert_type">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="rent_cost" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="rent_frequency" type="rent_frequency_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="number_of_bedrooms" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="available_date" type="available_date_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="property_description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="main_photo_url" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="branch_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="property_type" type="property_type_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="building_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="street_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="postcode" type="ukPostCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="furnished" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="location_area" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="agent_advert_reference" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="original_html_file" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="static_advert_url" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="rent_frequency" type="rent_frequency_type"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="rent_frequency_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="per month"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="per week"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Per Month"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Per Week"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Per month"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Per week"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="property_type" type="property_type_type"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="property_type_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Room"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="House"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Flat"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="room"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="house"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="flat"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="property_agent" type="property_agent_type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="property_agent_type">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="company_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="available_date_type">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:date"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Now"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="now"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="NOW"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="harvester_version_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9]+\.)?([0-9]+\.)?([0-9]+)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ukPostCode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="header" type="header_type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="header_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="harvest_run_info" type="harvest_run_info_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="property_agent" type="property_agent_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:element name="property_adverts" type="property_adverts_type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="property_adverts_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="header" type="header_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="adverts" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="adverts" type="adverts_type">
        <xs:unique name="unique_original_html_file">
            <xs:selector xpath="property_advert"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@original_html_file"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="unique_agent_advert_reference">
            <xs:selector xpath="property_advert"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@agent_advert_reference"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="unique_static_advert_url">
            <xs:selector xpath="property_advert"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@static_advert_url"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="adverts_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="property_advert" type="property_advert_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:schema>
```

I've only been using XML schema's for two days so please be patient with my newb question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies for putting so much code on here. I have seen lots of code snippets talking about uniqueness but none of those snippets worked when I inserted them into my XML schema. So I need an answer that works with all my code... maybe I added the snippets in the wrong place, hence why it's essential to see any answers in context to all my code.

Comment: Putting all the code is actually very good, because it allows anybody to reproduce your error and investigate. Without the entire code, I probably would not have been able to catch the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique constraint in your schema is not considered at all, because in the complex type property_adverts_type, you redefine an element named adverts with the implied complex type xs:anyType (so, it would accept pretty much anything under adverts elements). Instead, you should refer to the global element declaration for adverts using a ref attribute.

In short, you need to replace

```
<xs:element name="adverts" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

with

```
<xs:element ref="adverts" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

I have checked locally that doing so returns an identity constraint error on your document.

Comment: Also, you seem to use the attribute name instead of ref at many other places, so that all your global element declarations (except for the property_adverts one) are ignored as well.